# How to use boost::blank

Tags: c++, boost

I want to add empty values to `int` and `double` with the help of `boost::blank`. Later, I want to check if these values are empty. I have had a hard time finding information on the functionality of `boost::blank`. Can someone help with some examples of how to use `boost::blank`?

Answer (score 4):

[`boost::blank`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/blank.hpp) is not quite what you're looking for.

Here's what `boost::blank` is:

```
struct blank
{
};

// overloaded operators
// ...
```

It could be useful if you were creating a `std::variant` (or `boost::variant`) and wanted an "empty variant" like so:

```
std::variant<boost::blank, int, double, char> my_variant;
```

If you want to add an "empty" value for simply an `int` or a `double` in isolation, you should use `std::optional<int>` (`std::optional<double>`)

You can check for empty values with a [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) like so:

```
std::optional<int> value;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << value.has_value() << std::endl; // "false"
```

It's also implicitly convertible to `bool`, so you can check for a value in an `if` like so:

```
if (value)
    std::cout << "Has a value: " << *value << std::endl; // branch not taken
```

And finally, you can ask to use a default if there's no value, like so:

```
std::cout << value.value_or(0) << std::endl; // "0"
```

### [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ecvdTGf76)

---

If `boost::blank` is really what you're looking for, let's revisit the `std::variant<blank, int, double>` scenario.

Construct an  "empty" variant:

```
std::variant<boost::blank, int, double> my_variant;
```

or equivalently,

```
std::variant<blank, int, double> my_variant = boost::blank{};
```

Next, define visitors for each type:

```
struct my_visitor
{
    void operator()(boost::blank) const
    {
        std::cout << "Variant is empty\n";
    }
    void operator()(int i) const
    {
        std::cout << "Variant has int with value " << i << std::endl;
    }
    void operator()(double d) const
    {
        std::cout << "Variant has double with value " << d << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And we can execute the appropriate function using `std::visit`:

```
// int
my_variant = 42;
std::visit(visitor, my_variant);

// double
my_variant = 1337.0;
std::visit(visitor, my_variant);

// reset to empty
my_variant = boost::blank{};
std::visit(visitor, my_variant);
```

You can also check for an "empty" `variant` by calling `holds_alternative`:

```
if (std::holds_alternative<blank>(my_variant))
    std::cout << "Variant is empty\n";
```

### [Demo with `variant`](https://godbolt.org/z/6Mq6oEx5e)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i needed the variant one, but i did not notice that blank belonged to variant.

Comment: @Meng: "Belong" is a little strong. It's more like "Variant is the obvious application of blank". You can use `boost::blank` for anything else you want; it's such a simple class it really only exists out of convenience. And if it's your only dependency on `boost`, then it's probably not worth it instead of writing it yourself.